# Simple range search in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, activerecord

I'm new to ROR and I'm trying to implement a simple search which should allow a user to search for hikes that match a certain range of difficulty. The form is properly displayed and I do not get any error messages, the problem is that no search results are dispayed.

I've been trying to solve this for a whole day now, so any help is extremely appreciated!

Index.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag wanderungens_path, :method => 'get' do %>
<p>
<%= number_field_tag ':search[dauer_von]', @search.dauer_von %>
<%= number_field_tag ':search[dauer_bis]', @search.dauer_bis %>
<%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Wanderungens_controller.rb

```
def index
 @search = WanderungenSearch.new(params[:search])
 @wanderungens = @search.scope
end
```

wanderungen_search.rb

```
class WanderungenSearch
  attr_reader :dauer_von, :dauer_bis

def initialize(params)
  params ||= {}
  @dauer_von = params[:dauer_von]
  @dauer_bis = params[:dauer_bis]
end

def scope
    Wanderungen.where('zeitdauer BETWEEN ? AND ?', @dauer_von, @dauer_bis)
end
```

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ri1YNjl1_hA

I'm on Rails 4.0.0 and Ruby 2.0.0

Update: This is the code where @Wanderungens is displayed:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>User</th>
  <th>Schwierigkeitsgrad</th>
  <th>Zeitdauer</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<% @wanderungens.each do |wanderungen| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= wanderungen.description %></td>
    <td><%= wanderungen.user.email if wanderungen.user %></td>
    <td><%= wanderungen.schwierigkeitsgrad.description if wanderungen.schwierigkeitsgrad %></td>
    <td><%= wanderungen.zeitdauer if wanderungen.zeitdauer %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', wanderungen %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_wanderungen_path(wanderungen) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', wanderungen, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If I search from 1 to 2, the following request is generated:

```
http://localhost:3000/wanderungens?utf8=%E2%9C%93&%3Asearch[dauer_von]=1&%3Asearch[dauer_bis]=2
```

Comment: do you have entries in `wanderugens` table which match the criteria of `where` condition

Comment: try https://github.com/pry/pry and add binding.pry (debug) statements in the code.

Comment: @RajarshiDas yes, zeitdauer is a column of the wanderungens table and contains instances that should match the search!

Comment: @bbqbrisket thanks for the tip, unfortunately i did not get along with pry. i'm really just getting startet with rails.

Comment: Can you post the code, where @wanderungens is displayed in index.html.erb? Thx.

Comment: @Valentin Sidenote: You'll have it much easier writing a Rails app in pure English.

Comment: Can you find the sql statement with "zeitdauer BETWEEN 1 AND 2" in log/development.log? Just to ensure, that the scope method is invoked...

Comment: @Chrisian there seems to be a problem, the log sais "zeitdauer BETWEEN NULL AND NULL"

Comment: @Valentin got look the `params` are not getting so it is set `null` from so you need to debug `@dauer_von = params[:dauer_von]` and `@dauer_bis = params[:dauer_bis]`

Comment: @RajarshiDas thanks for the hint, i altough ended up integrating the desired functionality with the ransack gem which was really easy and worked just fine!